# Attempted import error: 'makeObservable' is not exported from 'mobx'

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-lite

```
import React from 'react'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'; //Cause of Error

export default observer(App); //At the bottom of the code
```

the only line causing an error is `import { observer } from 'mobx-react';` and gives my the following error

```sh
./node_modules/mobx-react-lite/es/utils/assertEnvironment.js
Attempted import error: 'makeObservable' is not exported from 'mobx'.
```

Comment: Fixed it.. Didn't import mobx in the project npm install mobx --save

Comment: Can you elaborate what did you do exactly... I am facing same issue... I have mobx present in package.json

Comment: npm install mobx --save (in cmd in the file location of your react project)

Comment: also install mobx-react and mobx-react-lite

Answer (score 2):

update mobx to last version and try again

Comment: Please add more details in your answer not just the fix.

Answer (score 1):

While building my project, I encountered an error in my console similar to the following:

```
Failed to compile.
./somefile/some.file.js
Attempted import error: 'makeObservable' is not exported from 'mobx'.
```

This issue arises because versions 5 and below of the `mobx` library do not include an exported makeObservable member in their interface. You can verify this by checking your `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` file for the installed version. To resolve this issue, update the `mobx` library to the latest version. I am currently using the following versions:

```
"mobx": "6.8.0",
"mobx-react": "7.6.0",
```

Updating to these versions should resolve the issue.